# Dell T5500 randomly freezing

Tags: bios, freeze

From past day, I'm facing this issue of random computer freezing. I checked Windows integrity via cmd, cleaned RAM, mobo, unplugged, and plugged back everything. Tried uninstalling some newly added softwares. Nothing fixed it. Then I updated bios and ran system diagnosis utility in BIOS. It's even freezing system in BIOS after it completes 3-5% diagnose.

So I'm getting a hunch that it's Power Supply PSU?

Kindly tell me should I find original PSU or I should replace it with some other brand. Current PSU is 875W (299 version)

SPECS:

- Dell T5500 (original mobo)
- Zotac Gtx 1060 3G
- 250 SAMSUNG SSD
- 1TB Segate HDD
- 512 G WD HSD
- 32G RAM

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Genuine-Dell-Precision-Workstation-Compatible/dp/B0097DON18

Comment: Are you sure it's PSU? That's causing problem.

Comment: I would suspect faulty memory as the cause of freezing.

Comment: Ok I'll confirm that. I've 8x4G Dimm